# Bone chanches it's roll even in Rest Pose

Tags: rigging

I'm doing a rig and faced with the following problem. The bone and it's parent have no any constraints or driver, but the bone changes it's roll even in Rest Pose. I see that at first time.

Here is a screenshoot: [image]

And file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WMr0iYCVd6Oq_r9mt8lo9fNM8D6hz3x3/view?usp=sharing

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a display tolerance, probably due to the extra tiny dimensions of the bone, if you tie a mesh to the bone, you wil see that there is no shift, even when the bone display is shifting from edit to pose mode.

Comment: Hmmm, really, there is no any shift in a mesh. Thank you!